# Shiny slide bar malfunctioning - sliderInput()

Tags: r, shiny, r-sf, r-leaflet

I am very new on `R Shiny`, but I do have a question rerarding the `sliderInput()`.

I am able to make the bar "work", but apparently it is not understanding the values `min()` and `max()` values correctly. Maybe I am missing something... Please ***note in the picture bellow*** that even though I am sliding the bar to don't show values higher than 0.1, I still have some polygons whit values higher than 0.1 appearing (image bellow).

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFz7.png)

**Data, available on Google drive**: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qF9-8-e0Y6P5X_NUY5XI_AfMhESOJMN2?usp=sharing

Here it goes a reproducible example....

```
library(shiny)    # for shiny apps
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leaflet)  # renderLeaflet function
#library(spData)   # loads the world dataset 

SU        = sf::st_read(dsn = "LinktoDataHere") 
SU$lrmm_SU= round(SU$lrmm_SU, digits=3)
factpal <- colorFactor(brewer.pal(n = 4, name ="BuPu") , SU$lrmm_SU) 



ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "life", "Mixed effects predictions for SU",
              min(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE), 
              max(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE), 
              value = range(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE),step=0.1),
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width = "50%")
)
server = function(input, output) {
  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas", group = "Gray") %>%
      addPolygons(data = SU[SU$lrmm_SU < input$life, ],
                  stroke = TRUE, 
                  fillOpacity = 0.5, 
                  weight = 0.2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "gray",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillColor = ~factpal(SU$lrmm_SU),
                  popup=paste0("Susc=", round(SU$lrmm_SU, digits=3)
                  )
                  
                  )})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem si your use of the input in your data filtering. Your sliderInput is a range, so two values, but you filter it using it as it was a single value. Either you do not make it a range in the UI, or you filter it correctly in your server part. If it's a range, using a reactive value to create/modify your data on the fly is your best bet.

Also, your popup and your fill coloring were both looking into the complete `SU` dataset, not the filtered one. You need to use again your new reactive to get the right value:

```
library(shiny)    # for shiny apps
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leaflet)  # renderLeaflet function
#library(spData)   # loads the world dataset 
SU        = sf::st_read(dsn = "SU.shp") 
SU$lrmm_SU= round(SU$lrmm_SU, digits=3)
factpal <- colorFactor(brewer.pal(n = 4, name ="BuPu") , SU$lrmm_SU) 



ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput(inputId = "life", "Mixed effects predictions for SU",
              min(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE), 
              max(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE), 
              value = range(SU$lrmm_SU, na.rm = TRUE),
              step=0.1),
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width = "100%")
)
server = function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    dat <- SU[SU$lrmm_SU > min(input$life), ]
    dat <- dat[dat$lrmm_SU < max(input$life), ]
    return(dat)
  })
  
  output$map <-  renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas", group = "Gray") %>%
      addPolygons(data = data(),
                  stroke = TRUE, 
                  fillOpacity = 0.5, 
                  weight = 0.2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "gray",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillColor = ~factpal(data()$lrmm_SU),
                  popup=paste0("Susc=", round(data()$lrmm_SU, digits=3)
                  )
                  
      )})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To find these types of mistakes, I suggest you print your `input` in an `observe()`. It always helps figuring these little bugs!

Comment: Hey @bdbmax, thanks for the help. 
This indeed works! Will study closer the issue to learn more about this great tool! ;)